# What do we call a person who helps in doing discussions or does discussions?

Tags: single-word-requests

For example, a person who fights for the country is called a soldier. And what would be the appropriate tag for this question?

Comment: What sort of discussions?

Comment: Science discussions,to solve problems.

Comment: Professor.....?

Comment: Please give an example sentence where you would like to use this word!

Comment: For example,I go to an institute where we primarily discuss science.I am a (discussor) there!

Comment: The example sentence needs to be included in the question. Please take the help tour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**interlocutor**

> *Formal*
>
> A person who takes part in a dialogue or conversation.

http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/interlocutor

If you want something less formal, you could simply use:

**participant**

> A person who takes part in something

http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/participant

However, *participant* isn't restricted to someone who takes part in a discussion – it's someone who takes part in any activity.

Answer (score 2):

This answer address the "helps in doing discussions" part of the question.

**facilitator**

> one that helps to bring about an outcome ... the workshop's facilitator kept discussion flowing smoothly

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/facilitator

In business meetings you sometimes have a facilitator, who doesn't necessary know anything about the subject being discussed, but it tasked with keeping the meeting productive. I've seen this when the participants are being introduced to a new type of meeting.

Answer (score 1):

A person who discusses can be simply called a **discusser** (AHD).

Another word from the same source is **discussant**:

> A participant in a formal discussion.

(American Heritage Dictionary)

If it's a conference we're talking about, consider **conferee**:

> con·fer·ee also con·fer·ree  (kŏn'fə-rēʹ) n.
>   1. A participant in a conference.

(American Heritage Dictionary)

If it's a panel discussion, the participants are called **panelists**:

> a **member of a discussion** or advisory panel

(Webster's Unabridged)